# Ruby and linux, preferred setup?

Tags: ruby, linux, editor, text-editor

Mac's have TextMate as there preferred application for ruby development, but what would be the preferred application for linux? I need something where it's easy to work with multiple files, project structure and setup commands to run my ruby app or if it is one my merb app.Syntax highlighting is also a must.

Now I typically use Vim, but it's not the best for working with multiple files or with a project structure, even with VTreeView plug-in or multiple VIM windows.

So what would you guys suggest?

If you have better plugins to use for VIM feel free to mention them, I'm not ruling out VIM here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use Vim on both Windows and Linux for development in Rails (we have to use Windows in work, and I only use Linux at home). The environment is almost exactly the same for both platforms. Especially important for me is easy navigation between the various Rails components - from Controllers to views, partials and models, and quick navigation to test files.

Here are the plugins I use:

- [Vim Rails](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) by Tim Pope. The :R, :A and gf commands are the ones I use mostly for navigation.
- [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) for a project/explorer view.
- [NERDCommenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) for easy multi-line commenting.
- [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) and "[FuzzyFinder - Textmate](https://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate)" - allows you to quickly find files based on portins of a file name.
- [Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
- [Bufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42)
- [dbext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) for executing SQL commands and getting the results in a Vim buffer.
- [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) and the [ack plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) for a better grepping experience from within Vim.
- [VividChalk](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1891) colour scheme.

Answer (score 9):

[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) from [JetBrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/) works well for Mac/Linux/Windows, the price is 99$ but it's probably the most productive IDE for Ruby and Rails I have tested so far.

Answer (score 7):

[Setup Gedit to be almost like Textmate](http://grigio.org/textmate_gedit_few_steps)

Answer (score 6):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) with the [Rails plugin](http://www.aptana.com/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Ubuntu/Debian, plain old emacs with [ruby-elisp](http://packages.debian.org/etch/ruby-elisp) package isn't bad.  It's no TextMate, but it's not bad.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Netbeans on both linux and Mac

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Netbeans for Rails. Each release gets better and better and with 6.7 beta it's better yet. Using it on Windows and Mac -- under Linux it's what I'd use as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a vimmer, have you looked at [this](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/)? I have no experience with it, but looks quite good in the [screencast](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2139263225227275468).

Comment: The screencast you linked to no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Sublime Text 2 Text Editor, it is free and cross platform and lighter than any IDE, and then you can install the SublimeCodeIntel which will provide you with autocomplete features , you can do that through installing Package Control , then

```
 ⌘+shift+p → “install” → ENTER → “codeintel” → ENTER → Restart ST2
```

It is working perfectly with me and I'm totally in love with this smart editor .

You can find this helpful somehow if you wanna give it a try , http://www.rockettheme.com/magazine/1319-using-sublime-text-2-for-development

I'm using it with zsh Terminal http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/

Anyways if you are looking for a full IDE give netbeans a try http://netbeans.org/projects/ruby/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Aptana/RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/) on both Mac and Linux.  It gives a consistent experience for me no matter what OS I'm on.

I still don't get the excitement over Textmate...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use vim,  [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/10/10/coming-home-to-vim) post might be interesting.

Her is the [Fuzzyfinder Textmate vim plugin](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate/tree/master) that the post refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio is indeed very nice. Also Gedit does the job if you don't want a full IDE environment and are more inclined to do stuff by hand :).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are about ruby editors, so I thought I will add an answer on my linux setup.

I use Ubuntu with VM player (free) on top of windows 7. I dedicate 2 core and 2 GB to the vm. Benefit of using the VM on top of windows is that I can use linux just for development and windows for everything else. Skype, webex, and team viewer works in windows, but i find them to be flaky in linux. Also I use office once in a while, very easy on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [GMATE](https://github.com/gmate/gmate) for a while and I can say that I only need gnome-terminal to complete my ruby/groovy/python setup. It have themes imported from textmate and do some method/property code completion (not much ok? but it comes handy).

Edit: forgot to say that GMATE is a set of plugins for Gedit (default text editor on gnome)

Answer (score 0):

With Linux there are 3 really good IDEs and all are free. You have Eclipse, Netbeans, and Aptana... They are all very good and each have some benfits over the other, its more a matter of preference. I would suggest downloading all 3 and giving them a try to see which you prefer.