# What IDE / Editor do you use for Ruby on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, ide, editor

I've been using vim, but after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256365/what-ide-editor-do-you-use-for-ruby-on-windows) was wondering what is being used in the linux world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby and linux, prefered setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253982/ruby-and-linux-prefered-setup)

Answer (score 6):

There's also Netbeans: http://ruby.netbeans.org/

Comment: NetBeans 6.5 is scheduled to ship on November 20, 2008.

Comment: As of 7, Netbeans dropped Ruby support. Please consider signing this petition to ask Oracle to re-include official Ruby support in Netbeans: http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/re-include-ruby-support-in-netbeans/

Answer (score 5):

If you'd rather be using a light text editor instead of a heavy IDE, then I'd highly recommend going with GEdit with some additional plugins.

Here's an excellent guide on how to turn your GEdit into a "Linux Textmate":

[Pimp My GEdit](http://grigio.org/pimp_my_gedit_was_textmate_linux)

If you want more of a IDE, then Netbeans is the current benchmark for Ruby IDEs.

Answer (score 4):

I have used and really like Ruby Mine from JetBrains. It's been around since around 2008, here's the link for that: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html

Comment: This is a subscription-based product.  Boo

Answer (score 3):

I use [Diakonos](http://purepistos.net/diakonos).  Written in Ruby, you can script it with Ruby, and manipulate text with Ruby.  No dependencies (except Ruby itself).

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse with Aptana RadRails: http://aptana.com/rails

but if you need only Ruby you can use RDT instead: http://rubyeclipse.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Isn't RDT discontinued now and the lead developer hired by Aptana to incorporate his work into Aptana's RadRails?

Comment: Yes, but I think you still can install RDT separately from Aptana Rails, which makes sense if you're only using ruby

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org) - it has a whole slew of plugins for Ruby, and unlike many other editors with Ruby support, it is very stable.  There are edit modes + syntax coloration for erb, rb, javascript, haml, etc. etc.  I have it set up basically to mimic TextMate, with some Eclipse-isms.  It doesn't do code completion to the nines, but it does at least try to complete from the current buffer.  It also has very extensible key stroke configurations and the ability to record/playback macros.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you be using Ruby for the web?  Aptana IDE with the RADRails plugin would have to be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I really like using [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) for ruby and rails work.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want.

I personally use vim as an editor as the default ruby tools as the rest of my IDE.

If you are looking for a more "heavyweight" IDE look at Eclipse (http://rubyeclipse.sourceforge.net/) or netbeans (Google for link).
There are a number of in-the-middle options which behave differently and have different features.  Google is your best best when it comes to these.

Also - please see [Ruby and linux, preferred setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253982/ruby-and-linux-prefered-setup)
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-for-ruby
If I could close this question for being a dupe - I would.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't affirm an IDE is better than other. Everyone has its pros an cons.
When I'm lazy I'd use Netbeans because it's comprehensive. An overkill in computer resources, but usefull if you are learning.
I've had bad comments about Aptana... maybe some of you that recommend this may have to convince me otherwise.

GEdit + Rails plugin may be a good alternative. And VIM is awfully powerfull but the learning curve is steeper (but once you get the taste of it, productivity will increase for sure).

Comment: +1 because, to misquote WC. Fields, anyone who hates dogs and Aptana, can't be all bad.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

komodo Edit is the best choice.