# favorite ruby/rails ide for linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ide, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE / Editor do you use for Ruby on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/what-ide-editor-do-you-use-for-ruby-on-linux)

what do you consider the best ide for developing ruby and rails on linux?  thanks.

Comment: duplicate :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/what-ide-editor-do-you-use-for-ruby-on-linux

Comment: Drat - I *really* wish I could just vote "1" close vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll be the guy that answers "[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)" this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Arachnoruby](http://www.ruby-ide.com) or Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not for Linux, but I'd say Textmate anyway, it is reason enough to get a Mac :)

To be more serious, I would recommend **vi**, or more precisely [Vim](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/). 
It's more lightweight than anything else and still manage to do the job right, so for Linux I don't think there are any other options and for Ubuntu (and probably Debian and the rest of them) there is even a package, vim-rails, that contain a lot of scripts to ease up the development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an IDE. Rails isn't that complicated, all it takes is a text editor and a terminal.

So, I recommend that you use a text editor such as emacs, vim, gedit or whatever. The KDE/Gnome terminals are more than good enough. You might want to look into using ZSH instead of bash.