# Is there any good intellisense tool for coding Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, intellisense

On Linux environment, is there any good intellisense tool, like an IDE you use for coding Ruby on Rails?

And what about Windows environment, any really good smart editor?

thank you

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer

Comment: This has been discussed here already. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/253982/126216

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best one is of course RubyMine: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP

Answer (score 1):

Try Komodo Edit (free) or Komodo IDE (money):
http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Sublime Text 2 Text Editor, which is lighter than any IDE, and then you can install the SublimeCodeIntel which will provide you with autocomplete features , you can do that through installing Package Control , then

```
 ⌘+shift+p → “install” → ENTER → “codeintel” → ENTER → Restart ST2
```

It is working perfectly with me and I'm totally in love with this smart editor .

Anyways if you are looking for a full IDE give netbeans a try http://netbeans.org/projects/ruby/

Comment: Sublime doesn't have intellisense. It has autocomplete based on what it sees in the current file though.