# gedit vs kate for Ruby/RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, gedit, kate

I've been working with gedit because it is the standard offering with Linux (I'm a Kubuntu user), but several people have mentioned Kate. For a text editor, for the most part I want a clone of textmate. Is there any merit to the claim that Kate *is* a textmate clone? I seek comparisons =]

Comment: Gedit with the gmate suite of extensions (https://github.com/gmate/gmate) comes close to textmate.

Comment: looking at that package, thanks

Comment: Very closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253982/ruby-and-linux-prefered-setup , plus other questions with the tags "ruby" and "editor".

Answer (score 4):

There are redcar

http://redcareditor.com/

> Textmate bundles, Redcar supports Textmate themes and snippets.

Comment: FAQ says it's still beta. I'd rather go with something that has a following, at least for now ;)

Comment: I use redcar for Rails development and it rocks!

Comment: Actually we say it's still Alpha :) but it's pretty useable now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Textmate, but I have some experience with Geany and Kate on Ruby.

I prefer Kate because it's possible to view several files side-by-side in the same window. It's useful to see file dependencies (class and subclass, controller and model/view, etc.).

Kate save sessions, so the window will open next time as it was left.

I suggest KDE >= 4.7 due to some bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 1):

[SublimeText 2](http://sublimetext.com/2) (beta) is a cross-platform gui editor that is a lot like Textmate. I've been using it on an off on my Mac and Linux machines. Its fast and so far much nicer than anything else I've used on a Linux machine for development (except for VIM, but that's arguably a whole other ballgame).

Answer (score 0):

While not a "clone" (I don't think you're going to find that any time soon), check out [E-Texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) which supports TextMate bundles.

Comment: I think he works on Linux. E works on Windows only

Comment: Apologies. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120/which-text-code-editor-on-linux-is-most-similar-to-textmate then. It's a couple of years old, but offers many Linux options.